# Convert string to Datetime dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert this `7/3/2015 12:40:02 PM` to DateTime with format `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` I have done like this:

```
BreackEndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(configViewModel.EndPause, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I always get

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Note that you probably meant `M/d` rather than `dd/MM`, if that date is meant to be today...

Comment: Also, if the hour can consist of a single digit you should use `h` instead of `hh`.

Comment: No i want to put the day at the first place and not the month

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since months and days can have a single digit use

```
BreackEndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(configViewModel.EndPause, "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[The "M" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx#M_Specifier) (exemplary, [`d`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx#dSpecifier) works similar)

> The "M" custom format specifier represents the month as a number from
>   1 through 12 (or from 1 through 13 for calendars that have 13 months).
>   A single-digit month is formatted without a leading zero.

**Update**

Since the hour can also have a single digit you have to use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("7/3/2015 1:52:16 PM", "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
```

... so `"d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"` instead of `"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`. Note that the same applies to the minutes and seconds, if they also can have single digits use `"d/M/yyyy h:m:s tt"`. I hope you got the point now.

Comment: No i want to put the day at the first place and not the month

Comment: @MoezRebai: then swap day and month. You have edited your question, before it was _"...with the first element is month"_. If the first 7 is the month use my code, if that's the day use `"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`.

Comment: when I swap M and d it handel the excption because the first one is month

Comment: @MoezRebai: there is no exception if you swap day and month since both are valid dates. It all depends on your specification. It's just important that you use`M` instead of `MM` and `d` instead of `dd`.

Comment: I have added an image of the exception, in fact I swap the day and month but i get the exception

Comment: You have to use `DateTime.ParseExact("7/3/2015 1:52:16 PM", "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` since the hour can also have a single digit, so `"d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"` instead of `"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`.

Answer (score 2):

If your `7/3/2015 12:40:02 PM` is string, you need to use single digit format specifiers as [`M` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#M_Specifier) and [`d` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dSpecifier) like;

```
BreackEndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(configViewModel.EndPause,
                                    "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: No i want to put the day at the first place and not the month

Comment: @MoezRebai But you said in your question as; _with the first element_ **is month**. Anyway, just switch `d` and `M` each other than.

Comment: I just want to said that for the date I have the first 7 is month

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that worked well in my case:

```
        Console.WriteLine("deal with regex datetime: ");
        string input = "11/24 5:41:00 AM";
        DateTime newDate;
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        try
        {
            newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/d h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine("parse result: " + newDate);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error parsing input string. date format is wrong or string chaged " + err);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FORMAT(CM.TransactionDate,'hh:mm:ss tt')
```