# How to convert string dd-mm-yyyy h:mm tt to Datetime in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

It may be asked many time but still i cannot get the solution for this i have string in format like 24-12-2016 12:24 PM how to convert it into exactly same format like this into to datetime date type so far what i have tried is:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(callobj.CallStartTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
//   String CallStartTimeString = Convert.ToDateTime(callobj.CallStartTime);

var s = dt.ToString("d-M-yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime datetimes = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "d-M-yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In datetimes am getting like this 12-24-2016 12:24 PM but i need to get like this 24-12-2016 12:24 PM how can i do this ? as am new to c# can someone Helpme out Thanks in advance!! In every other question it just left till string but i need to convert it again to datetimeformat and assign to  other datetime datatype

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to Datetime dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206251/convert-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-tt)

Comment: i have tried like that only but am getting format like as i mentioned

Comment: No, in `datetimes` you're getting a `DateTime` value. That doesn't have a format. It's just a value. Your format and reparse step has no benefit.

Comment: Then i need to assign that string value to another datetime date which is in dd/mm/yyyy thats why

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but you can't assign a string value to a `DateTime` variable. Just specify the format when you need it in text form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Date Format to ddth mmm,yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272514/change-date-format-to-ddth-mmm-yyyy)

Comment: i need format like this dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM tt in datetime data type how can i achieve this

Comment: The `DateTime` type doesn't have a format - it stores a date and a time, that's what you need to know. Now if you want to *show it to the user* as a string using a specific format, then when you're creating its string representation, just specify the format.

Comment: Maybe you want to change the format provider (culture info) of the current thread? Or maybe you want to change the regional settings of Windows (or whatever OS)?

Comment: Since you said `i have string in format like 24-12-2016 12:24 PM` and `...but i need to get like this 24-12-2016 12:24 PM`, my _real_ answer is "you don't need to do anything".

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
String str  = "12-24-2016 12:24 PM";
DateTime dDate  = DateTime.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Srring strDayFirst  = Format(dDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, since Jon and Theodoros are quite right with their comments, I try to clear all things if you let me..

> It may be asked many time but still i cannot get the solution for this
>   i have string in format like 24-12-2016 12:24 PM...

Honestly, based on it's name, your `CallStartTime` property looks like `DateTime` typed (*well*, actually it fits better with [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan) but that's irrelevant). But if you *really* sure it *is* `string`, I'm still not with you because you *can't* parse `24-12-2016 12:24 PM` string with `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt` format since they don't match *exactly*.

> how to convert it into exactly same format like this into to datetime
>   date type

Wait a second... A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. It's value stored 64-bit [`dateData` field](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,138) as [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks) (first 62 bits) and [`DateTimeKind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) (63 and 64 bits) of it. "Format" concept *only* applies when you try to get *textual* (also known as `string`) representation.

> In datetimes am getting like this 12-24-2016 12:24 PM but i need to
>   get like this 24-12-2016 12:24 PM

Sorry but I don't believe in you. Since your `datetimes` is a `DateTime`, *even* if you look at in debugger, you *can't* see any time designators with it. Those are can be *only* part of a string when you get string representation of your `datetimes`.

A `Datetime` instance looks like this in debugger;

[image]

Since your question is not very clear, there are 2 options;

1. You have a `string` as `24-12-2016 12:24 PM` and you want to parse it to `DateTime`.
2. You have a `Datetime` and you want to get it's `string` representation like `24-12-2016 12:24 PM`.

If you try to solve first, you just need to use `ParseExact` with `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt` format.

```
string s = "24-12-2016 12:24 PM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt", 
                                  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

If you try to solve second, you just need to use `ToString` method with proper format and culture settings.

```
string s = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```