# Convert a string like "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have to convert a string like 10/23/2017 12:00:00 AM to  DateTime.

(by refering [Convert string to Datetime dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206251/convert-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-tt))

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When i run the given code i get a:

> System.FormatException

The error further tells that

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How do i convert the string to a DateTime?

Comment: The problem is that `mm` means minutes - you want `MM` instead, at the start of your format string.

Comment: @CodeCaster: The example shows that the OP is using the invariant culture, so it shouldn't be a cultural issue.

Comment: @Jon absolutely right, nevermind, I've reopened.

Comment: Also read Jon's article called [Common mistakes in date/time formatting and parsing](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/).

Answer (score 4):

Most issues when parsing are due to incorrect format strings - and that's the case here. Look at your format string:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
```

That means:

- 2-digit *minutes*
- 2-digit day-of-month
- 4-digit year
- *2-digit* hour-of-half-day (1-12)
- 2-digit minutes
- 2-digit seconds
- am/pm designator

There are two suspicious aspects there:

- You're specifying minutes twice. You really meant *month-of-year* for the first part, which means you want `MM`
- You're specifying a two-digit hour-of-half-day, which is rarely used. I'd expect to see "8:00:00 AM" rather than "08:00:00 AM" for example.

So I suspect you want a format string of:

```
MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
```

Complete code:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```